# Extracting left side and right side of a string with operators in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe contains formulas from a random forest model ( the tree gathered by using getTree and formulas obtained by user defined function).

Example Input:

```
'%!in%' <- function(x,y)!('%in%'(x,y))

example <- data.frame(formulas = c("train %>% filter( balance > 599.5 & balance < 605.5 & 
                                                      contact %!in% c( 'cellular', 'telephone' ) & balance > 566.5 & 
                                                      job_group1 %!in% c( 'services' ) & 
                                                      education %in% c( 'primary' ) & month_group1 %in% c( 'jun' ) & 
                                                      education %!in% c( 'tertiary' ) & 
                                                      job_group1 %!in% c( 'blue-collar' ) )",
                                   "train %>% filter( day > 9.5 & 
                                                      month_group1 %!in% c( 'apr', 'feb', 'jan', 'nov', 'oct' ) & 
                                                      balance > 443.5 & balance < 597 & balance < 650.5 & 
                                                      job_group1 %!in% c( 'admin.', 'blue-collar', 'management', 'retired' ) & 
                                                      month_group1 %!in% c( 'jul' ) & 
                                                      contact %in% c( 'cellular', 'telephone' ) &
                                                      month_group1 %!in% c( 'aug' ) & housing %in% c( 'no' ) & 
                                                      education %!in% c( 'secondary' ) & 
                                                      education %!in% c( 'tertiary' ) &
                                                      month_group1 %!in% c( 'jun', 'may' ) )" ),
                      cluster = c("1","2") )
```

My expectation is extracting left side, right side of the operator, the operator and cluster name and save it into new dataframe.

Expected Output

```
desired <- data.frame( LHS = c("balance","balance","contact","balance","job_group1",
                               "education","month_group1", "education","job_group1",
                               "day","month_group1","balance","balance","balance",
                               "job_group1","month_group1","contact","month_group1","housing",
                               "education","education","month_group1"),
                       RHS = c(599.5,605.5,c("cellular, telephone"),566.5,c("services"),
                               c("primary"),c("jun"), c("tertiary"),c("blue-collar"),
                               9.5,c("apr,feb,jan,nov,oct"),443.5,597,650.5,c("admin.,blue-collar,
                               management,retired"), c("jul"), c("cellular,telephone"), c("aug"),
                               c("no"),c("secondary"),c("tertiary"),c("jun,may")),
                       Operator = c(">", "<", "%!in%", ">", "%!in%", "%in%", "%in%",
                                    "%!in%", "%!in%",">", "%!in%", ">", "<", "<", "%!in%",
                                    "%!in%", "%in%", "%!in%", "%in%", "%!in%", "%!in%", "%!in%"),
                       cluster = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2) )
```

I'm using R version 3.3.3 as the project requires it.

Comment: have you tried anything? seems like you could just use `strsplit` to split the logicals then again on the operators

Comment: I have tried gsub to capture left and right side, but failed to implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

example %>% 
#  tibble() %>% 
  mutate(formulas = str_remove_all(formulas, "^train %>% filter\\( |\\s*\\)$"),
         formulas = str_split(formulas, "&")) %>% 
  unnest(formulas) %>% 
  mutate(LHS = str_extract(formulas, ".*(?=(<|>|%in%|%!in%))"),
         RHS = str_extract(formulas, "(?<=(<|>|%in%|%!in%)).*"),
         operator = str_extract(formulas, "<|>|%in%|%!in%"),
         across(c(LHS, RHS, operator), str_trim)) %>% 
  select(-formulas)
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 22 x 4
   cluster LHS          RHS                                                   operator
   <chr>   <chr>        <chr>                                                 <chr>   
 1 1       balance      599.5                                                 >       
 2 1       balance      605.5                                                 <       
 3 1       contact      c( 'cellular', 'telephone' )                          %!in%   
 4 1       balance      566.5                                                 >       
 5 1       job_group1   c( 'services' )                                       %!in%   
 6 1       education    c( 'primary' )                                        %in%    
 7 1       month_group1 c( 'jun' )                                            %in%    
 8 1       education    c( 'tertiary' )                                       %!in%   
 9 1       job_group1   c( 'blue-collar' )                                    %!in%   
10 2       day          9.5                                                   >       
11 2       month_group1 c( 'apr', 'feb', 'jan', 'nov', 'oct' )                %!in%   
12 2       balance      443.5                                                 >       
13 2       balance      597                                                   <       
14 2       balance      650.5                                                 <       
15 2       job_group1   c( 'admin.', 'blue-collar', 'management', 'retired' ) %!in%   
16 2       month_group1 c( 'jul' )                                            %!in%   
17 2       contact      c( 'cellular', 'telephone' )                          %in%    
18 2       month_group1 c( 'aug' )                                            %!in%   
19 2       housing      c( 'no' )                                             %in%    
20 2       education    c( 'secondary' )                                      %!in%   
21 2       education    c( 'tertiary' )                                       %!in%   
22 2       month_group1 c( 'jun', 'may' )                                     %!in%
```

I tried to remove the `stringr` part and the `across`-function. Perhaps this works for you.

```r
example %>% 
  mutate(formulas = gsub("^train %>% filter\\( |\\s*\\)$", "", formulas),
         formulas = strsplit(formulas, "&")) %>% 
  unnest(formulas) %>% 
  mutate(LHS = trimws(gsub("(.*?)(<|>|%in%|%!in%).*", "\\1", formulas, perl = TRUE)),
         RHS = trimws(gsub(".*(<|>|%in%|%!in%)(.*?)", "\\2", formulas, perl = TRUE)),
         operator = trimws(gsub(".*(<|>|%in%|%!in%).*", "\\1", formulas, perl = TRUE))) %>% 
  select(-formulas)
```

Comment: I flagged as answer, but I am having a weird error. Error: Each variable must be a 1d atomic vector or list.
Problem variables: '.'. Have any idea?

Comment: Doesn't ring any bell. Does your original data look like the example or is there anything special about it?

Comment: even the example data gave me the error. I am reinstalling tibble. will update if anything happens

Comment: You can remove the "tibble()" - part. I prefer tibbles, but that's actually not necessary.

Comment: I forgot about the `R 3.3.3` requirement. It's possibly the problem...

Comment: @AnoushiravanR thank you, but it doesn't seem to work as expected... :-/

Comment: The error may imply the input is dataframe instead of vector. I really like the solution. Which R,dplyr, stringr tibble versions do you run?

Comment: On this machine: R 4.0.2, dplyr 1.0.5, stringr 1.4.0, tidyr 1.1.3, tibble 3.1.0.

Comment: I can confirm without tibble, the solution works on R 3.3.3

Comment: @MartinGal Maybe some tweaks are required but to me it looks great as is :) Glad it has been chosen.

Comment: I only have one question since I'm learning regex in earnest. In the following pattern `".*(?=(<|>|%in%|%!in%))"` you are looking to extract any character not followed by those separated by `|` am I right?

Comment: We look for anything `.*` followed by the operators (excluding them) which are seperated by `|`.

Comment: Oh thanks, I made a mistake. So `(?=(<|>|%in%|%!in%))` just make sure those character we are looking for are followed by them but they are not included in the output if I got your point right.

Comment: You are right. That's a so called _positive look ahead_ assertion, it matches a pattern with a suffix defined by `?=`. `?<=` matches a prefix and is called _positive look behind_. I'm still learning regex but it's totally worth the time. A very powerful tool.

Comment: Thank you very much I learned a valuable point and I'm sure I can learn even more from you. Yes I agree, I myself will soon start with Jeffrey Friedl's Regular Expressions book. I've heard it's a very good book to start with.